# Unable to connect to sql server named instance:error 26

Tags: sql-server-2012

To brief a little, I have created 2 VM's; both VM's have same h/w and s/w configuration. They are running Windows server 2012.

Have installed SQL Server 2012 on them; both installation have 2 named instances; like

VM1 have SQLmaster
VM2 have SQLSlave

Now, when I try to connect to instance in VM2 from VM1 I am getting error:26

> "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified"

Tried the solution/suggestions mentioned in below blogs but no luck.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/69b8e727-eb51-4de1-b298-b3ff316bd071/

Any idea, how can I get rid of this.

**NOTE:** I am actually trying to configure "sqlserver 2012 alwayson" on this servers but getting stuck here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after troubling shooting for a bit I found out the solution. Below it is ... hope someone will be helped.

**Resolution:**

> Open your network configuration(you can use the command `ncpa.cpl`)
>
> Click properties
>
> click on the IPV4 connection
>
> On the general tab -> change the preferred DNS connection from default
>   (127.0.0.1) to the exact ip address of the domain controller.